# How can I stop the program if the variable reaches zero?

Tags: python

My program is about renting cars, and whenever the user rents a specific car, its availability decreases. So, for example, if the available cars are 2, and the user rented the car twice, it will become zero. That being said, I want my program to stop all the calculations and the operation if the user wanted to rent the car when it had already reached 0. And print something like, "This car is not available."

My problem is that even when it reaches zero, it continues with the program. So the availability of the car starts going to -1, and the operation carries on. I couldn't figure out where I went wrong.

Here is my code:

```
print("Please select one: \n\t\b\b\b\b\b1. Car Rental \n\t\b\b\b\b\b2. Car Return \n\t\b\b\b\b\b2. Print the totals")
option_no = int(input("Option no.: "))
operation = 'y' or 'Y'
camery_availability = 3
pajero_availability = 2
altima_availability = 2
while operation=='Y' or operation=='y':
    if option_no==1:
        print("Select one of the available cars: ")
        print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        print("Model \t\tAvailable \tPrice/day \tLiability insurance/day \tComprehensive insurance/day")
        print("--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------")
        
        camery_price = 90
        camery_liability_insurance = 20
        camery_comprhensive_insurance = 50
        print("1. Camery  \t\t\b\b\b\b\b",camery_availability, "\t\t\t\b\b\b\b\bQR90 \t\tQR20 \t\t\t\t\t\b\b\b\bQR50")

        pajero_price = 150
        pajero_liability_insurance = 30
        pajero_comprhensive_insurance = 70
        print("2. Pajero \t\t\b\b\b\b\b",pajero_availability, "\t\t\t\b\b\b\b\bQR150 \t\tQR30  \t\t\t\t\t\b\b\b\bQR70")

        altima_price = 70
        altima_liability_insurance = 20
        altima_comprhensive_insurance = 50
        print("3. Altima \t\t\b\b\b\b\b",altima_availability, "\t\t\t\b\b\b\b\bQR70 \t\tQR20  \t\t\t\t\t\b\b\b\bQR50")

        car_type = int(input("Enter car type: "))
        No_of_days = int(input("Enter how many days: "))
        insurance_type = input("Enter 'L' for Liability insurance and 'F' for full insurance: ")

        #car type 1 (camery)
        if car_type==1:
            if insurance_type=='L' or insurance_type=='l':
                cost = No_of_days*camery_price
                insurance_cost = No_of_days*camery_liability_insurance
                tax = cost*0.05
                total = cost+insurance_cost+tax
                print("Cost: QR", format(cost, '.2f'))
                print("Insurance: QR", format(insurance_cost, '.2f'))
                print("Tax: QR", format(tax, '.2f'))
                print("--------------------------------")
                print("Total: ", format(total, '.2f'))
            elif insurance_type=='F' or insurance_type=='f':
                cost = No_of_days*camery_price
                insurance_cost = No_of_days*camery_comprhensive_insurance
                tax = cost*0.05
                total = cost+insurance_cost+tax
                print("Cost: QR", format(cost, '.2f'))
                print("Insurance: QR", format(insurance_cost, '.2f'))
                print("Tax: QR", format(tax, '.2f'))
                print("--------------------------------")
                print("Total: ", format(total, '.2f'))
            else:
                print("Error. Please enter the correct character")
            operation = input("More operation? [Y/N] ")
            if operation=='N' or operation=='n':
                break
            camery_availability = camery_availability - 1

        #car type 2 (Pajero)
        if car_type==2:
            if insurance_type=='L' or insurance_type=='l':
                cost = No_of_days*pajero_price
                insurance_cost = No_of_days*pajero_liability_insurance
                tax = cost*0.05
                total = cost+insurance_cost+tax
                print("Cost: QR", format(cost, '.2f'))
                print("Insurance: QR", format(insurance_cost, '.2f'))
                print("Tax: QR", format(tax, '.2f'))
                print("--------------------------------")
                print("Total: ", format(total, '.2f'))
            elif insurance_type=='F' or insurance_type=='f':
                cost = No_of_days*pajero_price
                insurance_cost = No_of_days*pajero_comprhensive_insurance
                tax = cost*0.05
                total = cost+insurance_cost+tax
                print("Cost: QR", format(cost, '.2f'))
                print("Insurance: QR", format(insurance_cost, '.2f'))
                print("Tax: QR", format(tax, '.2f'))
                print("--------------------------------")
                print("Total: ", format(total, '.2f'))
            else:
               print("Error. Please enter the correct character")
            operation = input("More operation? [Y/N] ")
            if operation=='N' or operation=='n':
                break
            pajero_availability = pajero_availability - 1
    
        #car type 3 (Altima)
        elif car_type==3:
            if insurance_type=='L' or insurance_type=='l':
                cost = No_of_days*altima_price
                insurance_cost = No_of_days*altima_liability_insurance
                tax = cost*0.05
                total = cost+insurance_cost+tax
                print("Cost: QR", format(cost, '.2f'))
                print("Insurance: QR", format(insurance_cost, '.2f'))
                print("Tax: QR", format(tax, '.2f'))
                print("--------------------------------")
                print("Total: ", format(total, '.2f'))
            elif insurance_type=='F' or insurance_type=='f':
                cost = No_of_days*altima_price
                insurance_cost = No_of_days*altima_comprhensive_insurance
                tax = cost*0.05
                total = cost+insurance_cost+tax
                print("Cost: QR", format(cost, '.2f'))
                print("Insurance: QR", format(insurance_cost, '.2f'))
                print("Tax: QR", format(tax, '.2f'))
                print("--------------------------------")
                print("Total: ", format(total, '.2f'))
            else:
                print("Error. Please enter the correct character")
            operation = input("More operation? [Y/N] ")
            if operation=='N' or operation=='n':
                break
            altima_availability = altima_availability - 1
```

Comment: share complete code.

Comment: Anyway remember to always prevent code from being uselessy repetitive, you could put that print statements into a procedure.

Comment: @iamtrappedman I did. Please take a look

Comment: Like @FLAK-ZOSO pointed out, you could simplify your code a lot if you would use some functions or even better a class for cars in your program. Like that it would be much simpler to debug the code.

Comment: Also, do you want to quit the program when a car is not available anymore or just quit calculating and showing that car type?

Comment: @Jon_Kle I can't use stuff that we still haven't learnt in the course :( But yes, I want to quit calculating and tell the user that this specific car cannot be rented anymore since it's not available.

Comment: Ah okay. Yeah, then i can recommend the answer of @iamtrappedman

Answer (score 1):

with every line like this, just check if it is available, if not just dont print it.

```
if camery_availability:
    print("1. Camery  \t\t\b\b\b\b\b",camery_availability, "\t\t\t\b\b\b\b\bQR90 \t\tQR20 \t\t\t\t\t\b\b\b\bQR50")
```

create another variable like `cars_available` that tracks total cars available i.e. sum of all available cars.

```
while (operation=='Y' or operation=='y') and cars_available:
```

```
cars_available = camery_availability + pajero_availability + altima_availability
```

and with every line that decrease the car_availibility add this

```
camery_vaailability = camery availibility - 1
cars_available = cars_available - 1
```

Comment: How would the new variable track the total cars available? Like, how can I do that?

Comment: I have pdate the answer